# Using Visual State Manager on a Style based on another Style

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have been having a lot of difficulties writing in xaml, understanding the visual state manager and using styles.

I have been creating a UWP app and largely using C# to develop my UI. However, I wanted to switch to using xaml but am inexperienced with markup languages.

What I am trying to achieve, and for the life of me can not figure out, is to create styles based on a "parent" style which has additional states, mostly to change the visibility.

Here is an example, I have created an instance of a default style called "NavigationViewItemStyle". I then have a few styles based on NavigationViewItemStyle. What I want to do is add additional states which I can trigger in C# to change the visibility of controls.

Below is my default style... just a simple copy

```
      <Style x:Key="NavigationViewItemStyle" TargetType="NavigationViewItem">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemForeground}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemBackground}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemBorderBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{StaticResource NavigationViewItemBorderThickness}"/>
            <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="NavigationViewItem">
                        <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Height="40" Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget="True">
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="PointerStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                        <VisualState.Setters>
                                            <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.(RevealBrush.State)" Value="PointerOver"/>
                                            <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.Background" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemBackgroundPointerOver}"/>
                                            <Setter Target="RevealBorder.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemBorderBrushPointerOver}"/>
                                            <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemForegroundPointerOver}"/>
                                        </VisualState.Setters>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                        <VisualState.Setters>
                                            <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.(RevealBrush.State)" Value="Pressed"/>
                                            <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.Background" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemBackgroundPressed}"/>
                                            <Setter Target="RevealBorder.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemBorderBrushPressed}"/>
                                            <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemForegroundPressed}"/>
                                        </VisualState.Setters>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                        <VisualState.Setters>
                                            <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.Background" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemBackgroundSelected}"/>
                                            <Setter Target="RevealBorder.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemBorderBrushSelected}"/>
                                            <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemForegroundSelected}"/>
                                        </VisualState.Setters>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerOverSelected">
                                        <VisualState.Setters>
                                            <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.(RevealBrush.State)" Value="PointerOver"/>
                                            <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.Background" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemBackgroundSelectedPointerOver}"/>
                                            <Setter Target="RevealBorder.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemBorderBrushSelectedPointerOver}"/>
                                            <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemForegroundSelectedPointerOver}"/>
                                        </VisualState.Setters>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="PressedSelected">
                                        <VisualState.Setters>
                                            <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.(RevealBrush.State)" Value="Pressed"/>
                                            <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.Background" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemBackgroundSelectedPressed}"/>
                                            <Setter Target="RevealBorder.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemBorderBrushSelectedPressed}"/>
                                            <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemForegroundSelectedPressed}"/>
                                        </VisualState.Setters>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="DisabledStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Enabled"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                        <VisualState.Setters>
                                            <Setter Target="RevealBorder.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemBorderBrushCheckedDisabled}"/>
                                            <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.Opacity" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDisabledThemeOpacity}"/>
                                        </VisualState.Setters>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="IconStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="IconVisible"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="IconCollapsed">
                                        <VisualState.Setters>
                                            <Setter Target="IconBox.Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                            <Setter Target="IconColumn.Width" Value="16"/>
                                        </VisualState.Setters>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                <Rectangle x:Name="SelectionIndicator" Fill="{ThemeResource NavigationViewSelectionIndicatorForeground}" Height="24" Opacity="0.0" Width="6"/>
                            </Grid>
                            <Border x:Name="RevealBorder" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"/>
                            <Grid x:Name="ContentGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition x:Name="IconColumn" Width="48"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                                    <ToolTip x:Name="ToolTip"/>
                                </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                                <Viewbox x:Name="IconBox" Child="{TemplateBinding Icon}" Margin="16,12"/>
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

I've then created a custom style based on my default style

```
<Style x:Key="HomeNavigationViewItemStyle" TargetType="NavigationViewItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource NavigationViewItemStyle}">
</Style>
```

What I can't work out is how I include additional states within my custom style to change the visibility of the control.

I.e. I have 4 different states the application can be in, and depending on the state certain navigationviewitems are either visible or collapsed.

To make things easy I want

```
<VisualStateGroup x:Name="NavigationViewStates">
    <VisualState x:Name="NavigationViewState1">
        <VisualState.Setters>
            <Setter Target="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
        </VisualState.Setters>
    </VisualState>
    <VisualState x:Name="NavigationViewState2">
        <VisualState.Setters>
            <Setter Target="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
        </VisualState.Setters>
    </VisualState>
    <VisualState x:Name="NavigationViewState3">
        <VisualState.Setters>
            <Setter Target="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
        </VisualState.Setters>
    </VisualState>
</VisualStateGroup>
```

But have no idea how to get this to work....

Can anybody help me or steer me in the right direction?

Comment: VisualStateGroup should be declared in XAML as part of control template. How did you want to trigger these visual states? In which conditions?

Comment: Thanks for your reply and yes this is where I'm having difficulty in my "base" style I have a VisualStateGroup attached to the control template. In my "child" style I have tried to attached a second VisualStateGroup to the control template that is somewhat independent (i.e. a visual state in the "base" visual state group my be triggered in combination with a "child" visual state). I want to triggered my "child" visual states through code (i.e. visualstatemanager.gotostate(item1, "NavigationViewState1")

Comment: I want to know under which conditions you want to trigger these visual states.  For example, In which condition, you want to trigger the 'NavigationViewState1'?

Comment: I have a command bar in my navigation pane with 3 appbartogglebuttons. A change in which appbartogglebutton is active (i.e. toggling an appbartogglebutton on will turn off the other 2) will change the visual state of the navigation pane content.

Comment: So, did you want to show/hide all the NavigationViewItems in NavigationView through the appbartogglebutton's status?

Comment: No I intend to have 3 different navigationviewitem child styles therefore anytime I create a navigation view item I can apply 1 of the three styles which may apply. My code can then iterate through all of the menu items which match type navigationviewitem and trigger the correct state (i.e. item1 is style 1 and navigationviewstate1 sets item 1 to visible, item2 may be style 2 and I'll also have a state navigationviewstate1 but instead this will be set to collapsed). Therefore my intention is to have a code that says for each item of type X gotostate("navigationviewstate1")

Comment: And depending on which style is attached the item will be either visible or collapsed... Well I hope it is simple as that and that send to me the easiest way with my limited coding knowledge

Answer (score 0):

> depending on which style is attached the item will be either visible or collapsed

There's an easy way to get your target. You could use [NavigationView.MenuItemContainerStyleSelector Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.navigationview.menuitemcontainerstyleselector#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_NavigationView_MenuItemContainerStyleSelector). You need to make a custom style selector to apply different style for NavigationViewItem, and in code-behind(the custom style selector class), you could show/hide the NavigationViewItem according to the item. By this way, you do not need to use visual state.

See the following code for reference:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="s1" TargetType="NavigationViewItem">
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"></Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="s2" TargetType="NavigationViewItem">
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"></Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="s3" TargetType="NavigationViewItem">
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"></Setter>
    </Style>
    <local:CustomStyleSelector x:Key="customStyleSelector" style1="{StaticResource s1}" style2="{StaticResource s2}" style3="{StaticResource s3}"></local:CustomStyleSelector>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid>
    <NavigationView x:Name="NavView"
                IsSettingsVisible="True"
                Header="Welcome" MenuItemContainerStyleSelector="{StaticResource customStyleSelector}">
        <NavigationView.MenuItems>
            <NavigationViewItem Content="Home" x:Name="home" Tag="home">
                <NavigationViewItem.Icon>
                    <FontIcon Glyph="&#xE10F;"/>
                </NavigationViewItem.Icon>
            </NavigationViewItem>
            <NavigationViewItem Icon="AllApps" Content="item1" x:Name="apps" Tag="apps"/>
            <NavigationViewItem Icon="Video" Content="item2" x:Name="games" Tag="games"/>
            <NavigationViewItem Icon="Audio" Content="item3" x:Name="music" Tag="music"/>
        </NavigationView.MenuItems>
    </NavigationView>
</Grid>
```

```cs
public class CustomStyleSelector: StyleSelector
{
    public Style style1 { get; set; }
    public Style style2 { get; set; }
    public Style style3 { get; set; }
    protected override Style SelectStyleCore(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        if (item is NavigationViewItem)
        {
            if ((item as NavigationViewItem).Content.ToString() == "item1")
            {
                return style1;
            }
            if ((item as NavigationViewItem).Content.ToString() == "item2")
            {
                return style2;
            }
            if ((item as NavigationViewItem).Content.ToString() == "item3")
            {
                return style3;
            }
        }
        return base.SelectStyleCore(item, container);
    }
}
```